# Artifactory not generating InRelease file for Debian repositories

Tags: artifactory

Artifactory Cloud is not generating `Inrelease` file or `Release.gpg` file for Debian repositories. Thus not allowing repository metadata signing.

I have uploaded a private/public gpg file to Artifactory settings, yet no signing is taking place in the repos.

Comment: Seeing the same thing in on-prem, in version 7.4.3.

Comment: I have the same problem with artifactory v. 7.35.2

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: Try using `gpg --full-generate-key` and manually specify a 2048-bit key.

I had this same issue, and just worked through it with jfrog support. I was creating key pairs using gpg, which defaults to 3072-bit keys. It appears that at least some versions of artifactory will silently fail to handle these keys. Once I used `gpg --full-generate-key` and manually specified a 2048-bit key, my key was recognized, and the InRelease and Release.gpg files were created (after recalculating the index).

If you go to Application | Artifactory | Artifacts and click on the top level folder, you should see an information panel like this:

[image: Screenshot of repo information panel]

When I was using 3072-bit keys, the final line "Signing Key" did *not* appear. This is despite the "Verification" process in the admin panel claiming that the key and passphrase were successfully verified.

Comment: I tried changing it to 2048 bits, and it still didn't work.

Comment: Does your repository information panel show a line with "Signing Key"? Or is "Created" the last line before "Package Information"?

Comment: There isn't any "Signing Key" line in the repository.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to define a passphrase when defining gpg keys.

You can add a passphrase when you are uploading keys through UI:

[image]

or, as in my case, with help of Terraform JFrog provider:

```
resource "artifactory_keypair" "some-keypair6543461672124900137" {
  pair_name   = "some-keypair6543461672124900137"
  pair_type   = "RSA"
  alias       = "foo-alias6543461672124900137"
  private_key = file("samples/rsa.priv")
  public_key  = file("samples/rsa.pub")
  passphrase  = "your-super-secret-passphrase"

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      private_key,
      passphrase,
    ]
  }
}
```

The gpg key was genereted with `gpg --gen-key` command.

After uploading the key with a passhrase and hitting **Recalculate Index** the InRelease and Release.gpg were created by Artifactory.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the gpg key not to be used, you can use the following command:

```
deb [trusted=yes] https://ARTIFACTORY-URL/virtual-deb-repo focal main
```